# Zabbix API hidden hostgroup/hosts

Tags: json, api, zabbix

I'm trying to get all hostgroups/hosts through the zabbix API.
I have used the following json requests:

```
{
   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   "method": "hostgroup.get",
   "params": {
      "output": "extend"
   },
   "auth": "6f38cddc44cfbb6c1bd186f9a220b5a0",
   "id": 1
}
```

The one for hosts differs only in "host.get" instead of "hostgroup.get".
But unfortunately some information is hidden. The frontend shows everything correct. But the API output is missing some hostgroupts/hosts.

It's bizarre because one of my self created hostgroups is displayed, the other one is not. Same happens with the hosts that are currently inside this hostgroup. As you can see I don't use any filter option.

Does somebody have a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What user do you use ? If that's not superadmin, maybe they do not have permissions for that group ?

Comment: @Richlv That's it! Thank you so much! If you write an answer, I will accept it. What a nifty solution ;)

Comment: Great, that was easy :)

Comment: Yes, embarrassing ;D But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user is not a Zabbix "superadmin", it must have permissions on those host groups. Otherwise you would not be able to retrieve groups or their members.